# Reading JSON data in netty server

Tags: java, json, byte, netty

This may be a "newb" question but here it goes anyway.
I am sending JSON data from netty client to netty server.
But the problem i am facing is netty server is not able to access/read JSON data.
In order to access JSON data in server, i need a encoder/decoder.
I am confused as to how to write this encoder/decoder ?
Anyone have any helpful ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [JSON-Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) or [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for serialization

Then write back to the client with this :

```
String jsonPayload = ...;
ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(jsonPayload, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
ctx.write(buffer);
```

If it's an HTTP server don't forget to wrap your buffer in a `DefaultHttpContent` !

```
ctx.write(new DefaultHttpContent(buffer));
```

For inspiration look the following examples :

- [HttpHelloWorldServerHandler.java](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/helloworld/HttpHelloWorldServerHandler.java)
- [HttpSnoopServerHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopServerHandler.java)

**EDIT :**

If you need to read the jsonPayload from your request, you could to this :

```
String jsonPayload = bytebuf.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I used [JSON-Simple](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/&ei=sC04UszSO5Gh7Aa6zoDYAw&usg=AFQjCNF-v1ms5A_ZPms7sXi63QZkAxwMog&sig2=UEleZfNWh-awYYydmkBgBg) toolkit.

Comment: I actually need a encoder/decoder at server and client level in netty. Toolkit you specified is for java. Netty is sending data in ByteBuf format, JSON-Simple would encode/decode Java object not ByteBuf.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question However I think the answers here are not the best solutions. The code bellow is smarter about extra memory consumption

Parse:

```
public T parse(ByteBuf byteBuf) throws Exception {
    InputStream byteBufInputStream = new ByteBufInputStream(byteBuf);
    return objectMapper.readValue(byteBufInputStream, klass);
}

public ByteBuf byteBuf(T value) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(value);
    return Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(bytes);
}
```